# Compress list of objects by matching attribute in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of objects which I want to "compress" into a smaller list of objects based on a matching attribute (`id`).

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, id, type, flag):
        self.id = id
        self.type = type
        self.flag = flag

eventlist = [
    Event("12345", "A", 1),
    Event("12345", "B", None),
    Event("67890", "A", 0),
    Event("67890", "B", None)]
```

How do I get a new list that looks like this? It should prefer defined values over `None` and disregard attribute `type`.

```
compressed = [
    Event("12345", 1),
    Event("67890", 0)]
```

edit: Better formulated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813818/merge-list-of-objects-into-consistent-list-based-on-common-matching-attribute-in). This can be deleted...

Comment: You want to remove the `type` attribute as well? Then why adding it in the first place?

Comment: `compressed = [Event(id=event.id, type=None, flag=event.flag) for event in events if event.flag is not None]`

Comment: It's not possible to create an `Event` object  with `Event("12345", 1)` because _all_ parameters are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. It should work.

```
eventDict={}
for e in eventlist:
     eventdict[e.id]=e.flag if e.flag is not None else eventDict[e.id]
compressed = [Event(k, None, v) for k,v in eventdict.items()]
```

Comment: Thanks, technically it works, but for the sake of simplicity I missed 5 more attributes of `Event` objects. How would I do it if there are more (they are identical per Event ID)?