# Merge list of objects into consistent list based on common matching attribute in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of objects which I want to "compress" into a smaller list of objects based on a matching attribute (`id`) and optional class parameters.

```
class Case:
    def __init__(self, id, formtype, age, fever=None, cough=None, gender=None):
        self.case_id = case_id
        self.form_type = formtype
        self.age = age
        self.fever = fever
        self.cough = cough
        self.gender = gender

caselist = [
    Case(id="12345", formtype="A", age=12, fever=1, gender="female"),
    Case(id="12345", formtype="B", age=12, cough=0),
    Case(id="67890", formtype="A", age=34, fever=0, gender="male"),
    Case(id="67890", formtype="B", age=34, cough=1),
    Case(id="75321", formtype="A", age=2, fever=0, gender="male")
]
```

How do I get a new list that looks like this? It should choose `formtype="B"` over `formtype="A"`.

```
compressed = [
    Case("12345", "B", 12, 1, 1, "female"),
    Case("67890", "B", 34, 0, 1, "male"),
    Case("75321", "A", 2, 0, "male")
]
```

I tried to compress it with a dict with no luck:

`compressed = [Case(id=case.id, formtype=None, age=case.age) for event in caselist if case.formtype == 'A']`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: see edit of original post

Comment: why not just `compressed = [case for case in caselist if case.formtype == "B"]`? Plus, you don't seem to actually have the field `flag` in `Case`.

Comment: Your if statement is only going to grab the cases with formtype A since you have the if statement `if case.formtype == 'A'`

Comment: @Kendas - because it neglects attributes from the other cases which share the same ID

Comment: are the form_types always going to be in that layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by id and keep the objects that have a "B" form_type  for duplicate id's that have a "B" formtype or else just leave as is, if you want to use any attributes not set in "B you can iterate over the attributes using getattr and setattr to set any previously unset attributes in B, you cannot hard code what to set or what not to set unless you know in advance what is set in A  and/or what is set in B:

```
class Case:
    def __init__(self, id, formtype, age, fever=None, cough=None, gender=None):
        self.case_id = id
        self.form_type = formtype
        self.age = age
        self.fever = fever
        self.cough = cough
        self.gender = gender

    def __iter__(self):
        for ele in ["case_id", "form_type", "age",
                    "fever", "cough", "gender"]:
            yield ele


caselist = [
    Case(id="12345", formtype="A", age=12, fever=1, gender="female"),
    Case(id="12345", formtype="B", age=12, cough=0),
    Case(id="67890", formtype="A", age=34, fever=0, gender="male"),
    Case(id="67890", formtype="B", age=34, cough=1),
    Case(id="75321", formtype="A", age=2, fever=0, gender="male")
]

d = {}

for c in caselist:
    if c.case_id not in d:
        d[c.case_id] = c
    elif d[c.case_id].form_type != "B" and c.form_type == "B":
        tmp = d[c.case_id]
        for attr in c:
            if getattr(c, attr) is None:
                setattr(c, attr, getattr(tmp, attr))
        d[c.case_id] = c

caselist[:] = d.values()
print(caselist)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite a bit longer than what you where going for but this works. It creates seperate lists of `A` forms and `B` forms. It then loops over the `B` forms and looks for a matching `A` form. If it finds a match then it changes adds all the `A` values to the `B` form

```
def merge(acases, bcases):
    newlist = []
    for b in bcases:
        for a in acases[:]:
            if b.id == a.id:
                if not b.cough:
                    b.cough = a.cough
                if not b.fever:
                    b.fever = a.fever
                if not b.gender:
                    b.gender = a.gender
                newlist.append(b)
                acases.remove(a)
    newlist += acases
    return newlist


caselist = [
    Case(id="12345", formtype="A", age=12, fever=1, gender="female"),
    Case(id="12345", formtype="B", age=12, cough=0),
    Case(id="67890", formtype="A", age=34, fever=0, gender="male"),
    Case(id="67890", formtype="B", age=34, cough=1),
    Case(id="75321", formtype="A", age=2, fever=0, gender="male")
]

acases = [case for case in caselist if case.formtype == 'A']
bcases = [case for case in caselist if case.formtype == 'B']

caselist = merge(acases, bcases)

for i in caselist:
    print '{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}'.format(i.id, i.formtype, i.age, i.cough, i.fever, i.gender)

12345 B 12 0 1 female
67890 B 34 1 0 male
75321 A 2 None 0 male
```

Here is another way to do it that is more efficient than my previous answer but not as efficient as @LeartS's answer. Both of these answers can handle different form layouts as well

```
def check_val(av, bv):
    if not bv:
        return av
    return bv

caselist = [
    Case(case_id="12345", form_type="A", age=12, cough = 0, gender="female"),
    Case(case_id="12345", form_type="B", age=12, fever=10),
    Case(case_id="67890", form_type="A", age=34, fever=0, gender="male"),
    Case(case_id="67890", form_type="B", age=34, cough=1),
    Case(case_id="75321", form_type="A", age=2, fever=0, gender="male")
]

d={}
caselist.sort(key=lambda x: x.form_type, reverse=True)

for case in caselist:
    if case.case_id not in d and case.form_type == 'B':
        d[case.case_id] = case

    if case.form_type == 'A' and case.case_id in d:
        b = d[case.case_id]
        b.cough = check_val(case.cough, b.cough)
        b.fever = check_val(case.fever, b.fever)
        b.gender = check_val(case.gender, b.gender)
    else:
        d[case.case_id] = case
```

Comment: This is really inefficient, it has a nested for loop. With 50k `A` cases and 50K `B` cases that's 2.5 billion operations, instead of the 50k required.

Comment: Actually, probably even more because it has `acses.remove()` inside the nested loops. `remove` on python lists is `O(N)`, so it's at least N^3

Answer (score -1):

Sometime I think the trivial explicit approach is also the best one, I would simply go with this:

```
compressed_cases_dict = {}
for case in caselist:
    if case.case_id not in compressed_cases_dict:
        compressed_cases_dict[case.case_id] = case
    else:
        if case.form_type == 'B':
            compressed_cases_dict[case.case_id].form_type = 'B'
            compressed_cases_dict[case.case_id].cough = case.cough
        else:
            compressed_cases_dict[case.case_id].fever = case.fever
            compressed_cases_dict[case.case_id].gender = case.gender

# if we really want just a list
cases = compressed_cases_dict.values()
```

Which, with your input, gives the output (after having defined a `__str__` function for the Case class):

```
In [1]: [str(c) for c in cases]
Out[1]: 
['case_id: 67890, form_type: B, age: 34, fever: 0, cough: 1, gender: male',
 'case_id: 12345, form_type: B, age: 12, fever: 1, cough: 0, gender: female',
 'case_id: 75321, form_type: A, age: 2, fever: 0, cough: None, gender: male']
```

Note how for id 75321 it has cough `None` instead of 0, which I think is better because you don't have any information on the cough parameter for that id. (Also for id 12345 the correct cough parameter is 0, not 1. I assume it's a typo in your example output)

It also iterates the original `caselist` only once and uses a dictionary to have O(1) id lookup

Comment: This only works if the format stays the way it is. So if you switch fever and cough for `case_id "12345"` it will give you `12345 B 12 None None female`

Comment: Yes, that's what explicit implies, the attributes must be manually specified. You "sacrifice" generability (which doesn't seem to be a requirement for OP, or we probably should generalize what's the "priority" indicator as well, instead of hardcoding B over A) in favor of clarity and expressiveness. IMHO

Comment: I assumed the attributes of each type are fixed (not necessarily the ones in OP's example, but fixed). If they aren't it's just a matter of generalizing the assignment (and OP should specify in the question)